# Normal form login button and facebook login button not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a login system for my blog. I successfully completed login system in PHP. also, I am using login with facebook. That I integrated and also working fine.
The problem I am facing that how can I validate both login buttons to prevent login directly into the admin panel by URL. please see code below.

```
<?php
// this is facebook button session  and  this is normal login button session
if(!isset($_SESSION['fbbbb']) || !isset($_SESSION['user_role'])){


header("location: /php-blog/index.php");

}else{
header("location: ../pages/index.php");
}
?>
```

Soi stored both buttons in session and working fine. 
But if I do validate them like above code.  then I can not enter in the admin panel. after pressing the buttons then i facing error below:-

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: From which page is this PHP script ? If it is from `/php-blog/index.php` or `../pages/index.php` you have a redirect loop.

Comment: header("location: ../pages/index.php");  this is the location where i have script and i want redirect user here after clicking on the buttons.

Comment: @Titus - waiting for a response.

Comment: You have a redirect loop. The page is redirecting to itself. When the page loads, it redirects to the same page and so on.

Comment: You may be able to prevent the loop by reading the request's headers to see if it landed on the page as a result of a redirect or if this is the first time the user has loaded the page.